# Is there any way to reduce number of if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to remove those if situations as much as I can. Here, I do have two if statements and I would like to write the same codes with one or none.

```
def ai_player(self, state, team = 1): 
    new_shape_x = np.asarray(state[1]).shape
    player1 = Minimax(n = new_shape_x, default_team = team)
    if team == -1:
        state = player1.convert_board_state(state)
    best_move = player1.decision_maker(state)
    chosen_succ, utility = best_move
    if team == -1:
        chosen_succ = player1.convert_board_state(chosen_succ)
    return chosen_succ
```

No Error, it is working fine with extra line codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the logic from `team == -1` from the logic that happens when `team != -1`:

```
def ai_player(self, state, team = 1): 
    new_shape_x = np.asarray(state[1]).shape
    player1 = Minimax(n = new_shape_x, default_team = team)

    if team == -1:
        state = player1.convert_board_state(state)
        best_move = player1.decision_maker(state)
        chosen_succ, utility = best_move
        chosen_succ = player1.convert_board_state(chosen_succ)
    else:
        best_move = player1.decision_maker(state)
        chosen_succ, utility = best_move

    return chosen_succ
```

There will be a repetition of code though.

In this case, you could also turn the two lines that repeat into one, making it clear that this part of the code is the part that repeats:

```
def ai_player(self, state, team = 1): 
    new_shape_x = np.asarray(state[1]).shape
    player1 = Minimax(n = new_shape_x, default_team = team)

    if team == -1:
        state = player1.convert_board_state(state)
        chosen_succ, utility = player1.decision_maker(state)
        chosen_succ = player1.convert_board_state(chosen_succ)
    else:
        chosen_succ, utility = player1.decision_maker(state)

    return chosen_succ
```

Now the variable `best_move` is gone. If you wanna still say that you are choosing the best move there, you could rename the `decision_maker` method to something like `choose_best_move`:

```
def ai_player(self, state, team = 1): 
    new_shape_x = np.asarray(state[1]).shape
    player1 = Minimax(n = new_shape_x, default_team = team)

    if team == -1:
        state = player1.convert_board_state(state)
        chosen_succ, utility = player1.choose_best_move(state)
        chosen_succ = player1.convert_board_state(chosen_succ)
    else:
        chosen_succ, utility = player1.choose_best_move(state)

    return chosen_succ
```

And there it is!

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with those perfectly readable if-statements?

As a not-totally serious option, you can replace any if with a dict lookup:

```
# ...
options = {
    False: lambda: None
    True: lambda: player1.convert_board_state(state)
}
options[team==-1]()
# ...
```

To make it even more concise (i.e. obscure), you can also use list. Indexing with False gives item 0 and with True gives item 1:

```
# ...
[
    lambda: None,
    lambda: player1.convert_board_state(state)
][team==-1]()
# ...
```